# Pandas ExcelWriter yields AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

While trying to create an xlsx file with pandas, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-201aac2da411>", line 1, in <module>
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_file2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'constant_memory': True})

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1945, in __init__
    self.book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path, **engine_kwargs)

AttributeError: module 'xlsxwriter' has no attribute 'Workbook'
```

My code :

```
import pandas pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'constant_memory': True})
```

Versions 
Python 3.7.3
Pandas 0.24.2

Comment: Could you give the full stacktrace? I suspect the error to be on an another line...

Comment: Edited for additional context.

Comment: Could one of your local python files be named `xlsxwriter.py`?

Comment: I searched that file and received two results. Deleting both did not resolve the issue

\Task3_1\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_xlsxwriter.py \Task3_1\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\tests\io\excel\test_xlsxwriter.py

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue. Previously, I had downloaded the xlsxwriter package and added it to my python pathmanager in Spyder. This conflicted with pandas. Deleting the path and xlsxwriter resolved the issue.